# get equivalent of pop method in as3 array

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

i am trying to get a element from a as3 array instead of using pop(). this is because pop() returns the element and REMOVES it , how can i get the element but not remove it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can access array elements by their index, i.e. their ordered position in the array. So for instance if you want the third element in your array, do this:

```
var myVar:MyClass = myArray[2];
```

Why 2 and not 3? That's because ActionScript arrays start counting at 0.

If you want the last element (like pop() returns), you can use the length of the array to find that element:

```
var myVar:MyClass = myArray[myArray.length - 1];
```

Why the minus 1? Since array indices start counting at 0, the last index in the array is always one less than the length of the array. Consider an array with three elements. They have indices 0, 1 and 2. The length of the array is 3.

Answer (score 0):

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/dev/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7ee5.html#WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7edf